# Backwards fill last instances of NAs in R Data Table

Tags: r, data.table, na

I have a data.table with a column like:

`c(58,NA,NA,NA,NA,13,NA,NA,NA,12,23,NA,12)`

I would like to fill only the two NAs before each non-NA value in the column by carrying backwards the next non-NA value. The result should be :

`c(58,NA,NA,13,13,13,NA,12,12,12,23,12,12)`

I have managed to do it with :

```
dt = data.table(V1 = c(58,NA,NA,NA,NA,13,NA,NA,NA,12,23,NA,12))
dt[, rleid:=rleid(dt$V1)]
dt[, num := seq(.N), rleid]

u=1
arr = c()
for (i in 1:(nrow(dt)-1)){
  if(dt$rleid[i] == dt$rleid[i+1]){
    u=u+1
    next
  }
  else{
    arr = append(arr,u)}
  u=1
}
arr=append(arr,1)

v=c()
for (i in 1:(length(arr))){
  for (j in 1:arr[i]){
    v=append(v,arr[i])
  }
}

dt[, len:=v]
dt[, val:=len-num]
dt[, V2 := fifelse(is.na(V1) & val<=1, nafill(V1, "nocb"), V1)]
```

This solution takes too long for a big data table. Any suggestions that are faster ?

Comment: solutions based on repeated `append()` will always be slow ... might be much faster if you pre-allocated the vector.

Comment: That's true, unfortunately for the first for loop I don't know the size of the final array. I can do that for the second loop but it's really the first loop that takes the most time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick and dirty `data.table` solution:

```
dt[, V1b := fcoalesce(c(list(V1), shift(V1, -(1:2))))]

# Or simply (as suggested by B. Christian Kamgang)
dt[, V1b := fcoalesce(shift(V1, -(0:2)))]


      V1   V1b
    <num> <num>
 1:    58    58
 2:    NA    NA
 3:    NA    NA
 4:    NA    13
 5:    NA    13
 6:    13    13
 7:    NA    NA
 8:    NA    12
 9:    NA    12
10:    12    12
11:    23    23
12:    NA    12
13:    12    12
```

Comment: You can write it more concisely as `dt[, V1b := fcoalesce(shift(V1, -(0:2)))]`

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the function given to you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76482639/5635580) by reversing the vector twice, i.e.

```
na_locf_max_backwards <- function(x, nmax){
  x <- rev(x)
  s <- split(x, cumsum(!is.na(x)))
  l <- mapply(\(x, y) {
        x[1:nmax+1] <- x[1]
        length(x) <- y
        x
      }, s, lengths(s))
  x <- unlist(l, use.names = FALSE)
  x <- rev(x)
  x
}

na_locf_max_backwards(c(58,NA,NA,NA,NA,13,NA,NA,NA,12,23,NA,12), nmax = 2)
# [1] 58 NA NA 13 13 13 NA 12 12 12 23 12 12
```

Comment: Nice but must be slow

Answer (score 2):

Another data.table solution:

```
dt[, V2 := fifelse(rev(rowid(rev(rleid(V1))))<=2, nafill(V1, "nocb"), V1)]

       V1    V2
 1:    58    58
 2:    NA    NA
 3:    NA    NA
 4:    NA    13
 5:    NA    13
 6:    13    13
 7:    NA    NA
 8:    NA    12
 9:    NA    12
10:    12    12
11:    23    23
12:    NA    12
13:    12    12
```